# How to access a webapplication running docker container to another PC with same network connection

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have runninng my node js and springboot application in docker container and its access by docker running pc on "localhost:3000" and "myipaddress:3000", then how can i access to the same on the another PC, I running an application through docker-compose up..